# How to pass a sorting method as parameter in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a `Task` class that contains an `ArrayList<Task> tasks`.
What I would like to do is create a sorting method, which makes the user choose how to sort this ArrayList tasks.
It must be the user, in `main`, who invokes the method to pass, as a parameter, the sorting method, which will then be done in the Task class.
how do i do this?

Comment: Please do add your approach and where are you facing the problem

Comment: I think there is already a method for this. At Lists there is the method `sort`, which accepts an `Comparator` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should utilize Comparator interface by introducing a method as follows:

```
void sort(List<Task> tasks, Comparator<Task> comparator) {
   tasks.sort(comparator);
}
```

Example usage of the above method to sort the list based on a task id field of Task class:

```
sort(tasks, Comparator.comparing(task -> task.getTaskId())
```

Notice that the sort method is void, meaning that it mutates the original tasks list.
If you have to keep the original list intact then the implementation of sort should be as follows:

```
List<Task> sort(List<Task> tasks, Comparator<Task> comparator) {
   return tasks.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have to initialize my sort method in a different class from the ArryaList is situated, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is totally fine. The implementation does not imply any limitations on where to define the sort method.